# Shared library for two projects

Tags: java, maven, build

I'm running two webapps (based on Spring, JPA and JSF) on the same tomcat server. Now my WARs beginning to get big in size which I would like to change. For development I'm using the embedded jetty/tomcat plugin - maybe this is interesting.

What I want to achieve is: Creating a jar which holds the classes which are needed for both projects, e.g. `Spring, Hibernate and MySQL` - I want to build those as a seperate JAR and deploy this on the server. My next thought was to provide this bundle to my projects as dependency with provided scope. That would shrink my WAR files.

Can I achieve this on a really simple way? It would be great if I could use the embedded jetty/tomcat server for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are more or less asking what has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273109/maven-tomcat-plugin-with-mysql-driver-in-catalina-home-lib); just add the dependencies you need.